# javascript no response codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have this drop-down dependent on the choices of the other two dropdown,

I already debugged it and the only error i see is, it never get success

here is my javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#GRADE").change(function() {
    var TRANCHE = {"TRANCHE" : $('#TRANCHE').val()};
    var GRADE = {"GRADE" : $('#GRADE').val()};
    console.log(TRANCHE);
    console.log(GRADE);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        TRANCHE : "TRANCHE",
        GRADE : "GRADE"
      },
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>EmployeeSalary/dependent_dropdown2/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#SAL_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.ID+"'>"+option.AMOUNT+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

and here is my controller

```
   public function dependent_dropdown2()
   {
       if(isset($_POST['TRANCHE']))
       {

            $data = $_POST['TRANCHE'];

            $data1 = $_POST['GRADE'];
            $this->output
            ->set_content_type("application/json")
            ->set_output(json_encode($this->EmployeeSalary_Model->getType2($data, $data1)));
       }
   }
```

why is it that it doesnt trigger the succes function?

Comment: Do you not get any error in this line `data:
        TRANCHE,
        GRADE`??

Comment: @Poonam its originally `data: {
      TRANCHE : "TRANCHE",
      GRADE : "GRADE"
    },` i copied the past code. im sorry. i updated it

Comment: on server side, are you getting both values?

Comment: have you checked in console ? what's the error

Comment: the console doesnt have any errors, when i chose something it just shows `Object {TRANCHE: "First"}
Object {GRADE: "9"}` but on the network, the response is just `[]`

Comment: Why are you creating object array like var TRANCHE = {"TRANCHE" : $('#TRANCHE').val()};
    var GRADE = {"GRADE" : $('#GRADE').val()};

Comment: i need to pass two variables to the controller. as seen above `$data = $_POST['TRANCHE'];

            $data1 = $_POST['GRADE'];` im not good in javascript so im not sure if thats correct

Comment: Okay np, check my answer

Comment: Try using `data : {TRANCHE : $('#TRANCHE').val(), GRADE : $('#GRADE').val()},`

Comment: as i have observed the data: doesnt matter. it just dont go to the success function. do you think i have something wrong with passing the data to the controller?

Comment: @kev_m check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the controller is not returning anything to the browser.
Try it without using the `output` class directly.

```
public function dependent_dropdown2()
{
  if(isset($_POST['TRANCHE']))
  {
    $data = $_POST['TRANCHE'];
    $data1 = $_POST['GRADE'];
    echo json_encode($this->EmployeeSalary_Model->getType2($data, $data1));
  }
}
```

It looks like the data structure being provided to `$.ajax` is off too.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $("#GRADE").change(function () {
    var posting = {TRANCHE: $('#TRANCHE').val(), GRADE: $('#GRADE').val()};
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: posting,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>EmployeeSalary/dependent_dropdown2/",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var select = $('#SAL_ID');
        select.html('');
        $.each(data, function (i, option) {
          select.append("<option value='" + option.ID + "'>" + option.AMOUNT + "</option>");
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: yes i think the contoller is not returning anything.  and i have no idea why

Comment: Are you certain the controller is getting called?

Comment: Are you certain that `$this->EmployeeSalary_Model->getType2($data, $data1)` is returning something?

Comment: nope. and thats the problem. how can i check it? `print_r()` is not working on this one

Comment: I asked two questions. Which did you answer?

Comment: im not sure weather controller or model isnt called. but if i made it dependent on one dropdown, or if i am only passing one data, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try, by removing object from the varibles,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#GRADE").change(function() {
    var TRANCHE = $('#TRANCHE').val();
    var GRADE =  $('#GRADE').val();
    console.log(TRANCHE);
    console.log(GRADE);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        TRANCHE : "TRANCHE",
        GRADE : "GRADE"
      },
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>EmployeeSalary/dependent_dropdown2/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#SAL_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.ID+"'>"+option.AMOUNT+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

**----------------------Added return code-------------------**

In return method use

```
public function dependent_dropdown2_asd() 
{ 
if(isset($_POST['TRANCHE'])) 
{ 
$TRANCHE = $_POST['TRANCHE']; 
$GRADE = $_POST['GRADE']; 
$data=array('Responce'=>200);
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode($data); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: as i have observed the data: doesnt matter. it just dont go to the success function. do you think i have something wrong with passing the data to the controller?

Comment: In console you have checked calling of function ?

Comment: i dont know how to check it.

Comment: where should i put `header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data)`

Comment: when you return. Put it in controller method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116453/discussion-between-anand-jain-and-kev-m).

Comment: can you please put the sample controller on the answer? So i can see it. im a little confused. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a little typo in your ajax call.
I think you have to pass the variables (TRANCHE,GRADE) in the data object of ajax instead you passed strings("TRANCHE","GRADE").
Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#GRADE").change(function() {
    var TRANCHE = {"TRANCHE" : $('#TRANCHE').val()};
    var GRADE = {"GRADE" : $('#GRADE').val()};
    console.log(TRANCHE);
    console.log(GRADE);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        TRANCHE : TRANCHE, //pass the variable
        GRADE : GRADE
      },
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>EmployeeSalary/dependent_dropdown2/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#SAL_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.ID+"'>"+option.AMOUNT+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

And rest of things looks good. you can debug the post request by just printing it like

```
 public function dependent_dropdown2()
   {
       if(isset($_POST['TRANCHE']))
       {

            $data = $_POST['TRANCHE'];

            $data1 = $_POST['GRADE'];
            print_r($data1);
           print_r($data2);
       }
   }
```

Comment: i cannot do something like`print_r($data1);
           print_r($data2);` because data is passed as json. so i cant chech the post data